# Extract differences of values of 2 given dictionaries - values are tuples of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as follows, I need to extract which strings in the tuple values are in one dictionary but not in other:

```
dict_a = {"s": ("mmmm", "iiiii", "p11"), "yyzz": ("oo", "i9")}
dict_b = {"s": ("mmmm",), "h": ("pp",), "g": ("rr",)}
```

The desired output:

```
{"s": ("iiiii", "p11"), "yyzz": ("oo", "i9")}
```

The order of the strings in the output doesn't matter.

One way that I tried to solve, but it doesn't produce the expected result:

```
>>> [item for item in dict_a.values() if item not in dict_b.values()]
[('mmmm', 'iiiii', 'p11'), ('oo', 'i9')]
```

Comment: Note that `("p11")` does **not** produce a tuple, you need to add commas to those single-value tuples to actually create tuples. If order doesn't matter, **use sets**.

Comment: thanks, order doesn't matter, I also tried with set, but it doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: @user14269252: sets let you produce the difference trivially. How is the output not correct in that case? Should the output be tuples again? Then just convert back to a tuple.

Comment: @user14269252: let me emphasise what I said earlier: **`("p11")` does not produce a tuple**, because there is no comma. `("p11")` is exactly the same as `"p11"`, while `("p11",)` (note the comma!) produces a tuple containing a single string. `set(("p11",))` then produces the set `{"p11"}`, while `set(("p11"))` produces the set `{"p", "1"}`. That's a big difference, and one way that your attempts to use sets may fail.

Comment: It is now clear thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, convert your dictionary values to sets, and subtract these:

```
{k: set(v) - set(dict_b.get(k, ())) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
```

The above takes all key-value pairs from `dict_a`, and for each such pair, outputs a new dictionary with those keys and a new value that's the set difference between the original value and the corresponding value from `dict_b`, if there is one:

```
>>> dict_a = {"s": ("mmmm", "iiiii", "p11"), "yyzz": ("oo", "i9")}
>>> dict_b = {"s": ("mmmm",), "h": ("pp",), "g": ("rr",)}
>>> {k: set(v) - set(dict_b.get(k, ())) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
{'s': {'p11', 'iiiii'}, 'yyzz': {'oo', 'i9'}}
```

The output will have sets, but these can be converted back to tuples if necessary:

```
{k: tuple(set(v) - set(dict_b.get(k, ()))) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
```

The `dict_b.get(k, ())` call ensures there is always a tuple to give to `set()`.

If you use the `set.difference()` method you don't even need to turn the `dict_b` value to a set:

```
{k: tuple(set(v).difference(dict_b.get(k, ()))) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
```

Demo of the latter two options:

```
>>> {k: tuple(set(v) - set(dict_b.get(k, ()))) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
{'s': ('p11', 'iiiii'), 'yyzz': ('oo', 'i9')}
>>> {k: tuple(set(v).difference(dict_b.get(k, ()))) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
{'s': ('p11', 'iiiii'), 'yyzz': ('oo', 'i9')}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
{k: [v for v in vs if v not in dict_b.get(k, [])] for k,vs in dict_a.items()}
```

if you want to use tuples (or sets - just replace the cast)

```py
{k: tuple(v for v in vs if v not in dict_b.get(k, [])) for k,vs in dict_a.items()}
```

Comment: Small correction - OP wants tuples as values, not lists - use `tuple(v for v in vs if v not in dict_b.get(k, []))`

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but why when I write it the other way round, it produces a weird result? {k: tuple(v for v in vs if v not in dict_a.get(k, [])) for k,vs in dict_b.items()}

Comment: I don't disagree. However more than once I have given an explained response where a simple piece of code has been given the answer - time feels imperative. I'd rather give a working solution up front and edit in an explanation. As a moderator please feel free to tell me if such a thing isn't permitted.

Comment: The weird result you're seeing is because you're iterating over the strings, as mentioned by Martijn, `("abc")` is not a tuple but a string, so the characters `a, b, c` are being processed individually. Add the comma `("abc",)` as described.

Comment: "However more than once I have given an explained response where..." unfortunately, it sounds like you are experiencing the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).  I understand your frustration.  My solution has been to skip the simple low-hanging fruit type problems and go after more complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see comments for explanations):

```py
>>> out = {} # Initialise output dictionary
>>> for k, v in dict_a.items(): # Iterate through items of dict_a
...     if k not in dict_b: # Check if the key is not in dict_b
...         out[k] = v # If it isn't, add to out
...     else: # Otherwise
...         out[k] = tuple(set(v) - set(dict_b[k])) # Subtract sets to find the difference
...
>>> out
{'s': ('iiiii', 'p11'), 'yyzz': ('oo', 'i9')}
```

This can then be simplified using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
>>> out = {k: tuple(set(v) - set(dict_b.get(k, ()))) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
>>> out
{'s': ('iiiii', 'p11'), 'yyzz': ('oo', 'i9')}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `if k not in dict_b` if you use `dict_b.get(k, ())` instead of `dict_b[k]`. You then subtract an empty set, producing the original set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I know, but I thought it was more readable this way. I used `dict.get` in my second solution.

Comment: but why when I run, it produces : {'s': ('mmmm', 'p11', 'iiiii'), 'yyzz': ('oo', 'i9')}

Comment: It's indeed a balance to strike between conciseness (easier to scan in a single read) and clarity. For this case, I think subtracting an empty set is clearer and cleaner, but it's a subjective call.

Comment: @user14269252: clearly not when we use your question samples. Try copying the dictionaries **in your question** and then run the code in my answer and the code in this answer. You get your expected output.

Comment: @user14269252 - that's because you're probably using strings not tuples as the values in `dict_b`. Try copying and pasting the dictionaries from the question.

Comment: @user14269252: you do need to take my correction to your question into account. If you are still using `("mmmm")` in your dictionary, then **that's not a tuple** and you get a `{"m"}` set.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution :

- First iterate through all keys in dict_a
- Check if the key is present or not in dict_b
- Now, if present: take the tuples and iterate through dict_a's tuple(as per your question). now check weather that element is present or not in dict_b's tuple. If it is present just leave it. If it is not just add that element in tup_res.
- Now after the for loop, add that key and tup value in the dict_res.
- if the key is not present in dict_b simply add it in dict_res.

```py
dict_a = {"s":("mmmm","iiiii","p11"), "yyzz":("oo","i9")}
dict_b = {"s":("mmmm"),"h":("pp",),"g":("rr",)}

dict_res = {}

for key in dict_a:
    if key in dict_b:
        tup_a = dict_a[key]
        tup_b = dict_b[key]
        tup_res = ()
        for tup_ele in tup_a:
            if tup_ele in tup_b:
                pass
            else:
                tup_res = tup_res + (tup_ele,)
        dict_res[key] = tup_res;
    else:
        dict_res[key] = dict_a[key];
print(dict_res)
```

It is giving correct output :)

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not a good answer.

Comment: `dict_b` isn't the same as the dictionary in the question - you're using strings not tuples

Comment: I didn't get you @TheThonnu. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Your `dict_b` = `{"s":("mmmm"),"h":("pp"),"g":("rr")}`. In the question, `dict_b` = `{"s": ("mmmm",), "h": ("pp",), "g": ("rr",)}` - notice the commas

Comment: Still, It is giving correct output. I will just edit it in a moment :)
Thanks for pointing it out.